# Pilot doesn't get in aircraft in "Destination Metropolis"

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

In this [LEGO Batman 2 'Destination Metropolis' walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRDYXJDOIPI) you can set at 7:51 a guy jumps down, gets into the aircraft and takes off.  When I'm playing, the guy doesn't get into the aircraft, thus blocking me from completing the level.  I can't attack the guy, or the aircraft.

What do I need to do to get the aircraft up in the air?

Answer (score 1):

If a triggered event does not trigger, you have to start over. First try to walk around the area (but it seems you tried that), hopefully it triggers somewhere else. There is nothing else you can do, because without the trigger, you cannot advance in the level. There was a save-station a few seconds before the event, so maybe you are lucky.

Sometimes it is possible to continue without the trigger, for example if you have to hit something but it is in a different location then it should be, but because you cannot grapple to the flying helicopter, it cannot be destroyed.

When this is still happening when you restart the level: turn off the xbox/playstation, turn it on, remove disc and insert it again. Sometimes it isn't read properly and this will most likely fix it. If it still persist, I think you are screwed.